# On the maximal powers of $q$ which arise in a quantum product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flag-varieties, homogeneous-spaces, schubert-calculus, quantum-cohomology

Let $X=G/P$ be a generalized flag variety (where $G$ denotes a connected, simply connected, semisimple complex linear algebraic group and $P$ a parabolic subgroup). In [this paper by Fulton and Woodward](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112183) the authors give a description of the minimal powers of $q$ which arise in a quantum product $\sigma_u\star\sigma_v$ of two Schubert cycles $\sigma_u$ and $\sigma_v$. These powers are given by the minimal elements in the set of all degrees of chains from $u$ to $v$ (cf. [Theorem 9.1, Fulton-Woodward](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112183)).

Question: Are there simliar results on the maximal powers of $q$ which arise in a quantum product? I would like to have a combinatorial description analogous to the "chain business" in the cited paper. There might be developments which I am not aware of and which are helpful to answer this questions. References in this direction are very welcome.

Let me ask a second question which is more concretely. Can you compute the maximal powers of $q$ which arise in the quantum product $[\{\mathrm{pt}\}]\star[\{\mathrm{pt}\}]$ of the classes of two points? (I know some results in this direction for Grassmannians and the like, but I forgot where I have read these explicit computations. Except this, I am seeking for a uniform description which works in the $G/P$-generality.)

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be a simple root not in the set of simple roots of $P$. Then I think I can compute at least the maximal powers of $q$ which arise in the quantum product $\sigma_{s_\alpha}\star[\{\mathrm{pt}\}]$. This should be an immediate consequence of the "Quantum Chevalley Formula" in the paper by Fulton-Woodward. Do you have further results in this direction?